# IDirectoryObject::SetObjectAttributes returns no error, but no attributes is updated

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to update the attribute of a user in Active Directory. I've logged in as Domain Admins and executed the following code locally:

```
LPCWSTR pwszADsPath = L"LDAP://CN=MyUserName,CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=YYY,DC=com";

// Bind to the root of the current domain.
hr = ADsOpenObject(pwszADsPath,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
    IID_IDirectorySearch,
    (void**)&pDirObject);    

// Bind to the object
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    DWORD dwReturn = 0;
    ADSVALUE givenName;
    ADSVALUE phoneValue[2];

    ADS_ATTR_INFO  attrInfo[] = {   
        {L"givenName",      ADS_ATTR_UPDATE, ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING, &givenName, 1},
        {L"otherTelephone", ADS_ATTR_UPDATE, ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING, phoneValue, 2}
    };

    givenName.dwType           = ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
    givenName.CaseIgnoreString = L"Janet";

    phoneValue[0].dwType = ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
    phoneValue[0].CaseIgnoreString = L"425 844 1234";

    phoneValue[1].dwType = ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
    phoneValue[1].CaseIgnoreString = L"425 924 4321"; 

    hr = pDirObject->SetObjectAttributes(attrInfo, sizeof(attrInfo) / sizeof(ADS_ATTR_INFO), &dwReturn);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"%d Attributes updated\n", dwReturn);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"SetObjectAttributes failed. hr=0x%x\n", hr);
    }

    pDirObject->Release();
}
```

When I run the program, I'm always getting `0 Attributes updated`. And I confirm in `AD Users And Computers`, the givenName is not updated.

The `pwszADsPath` is correctly copied from ADSI edit, and I have write privileges, what did I miss?

Comment: May sound daft, but have you tried declaring `givenName` as an `ADSVALUE` ***array*** (of size 1, just like you have for `attrInfo`). To you and I, this would seem to be the same as you have already - just trying to think in Microsoft mode!

Comment: @Adrian No, it does not work. I've tried to add add another attribute as array, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I tried compiling a part of your code and got the following **error** (MSVC, in Visual Studio 2019):

```
ADS_ATTR_INFO  attrInfo[] = {
    {L"givenName",      ADS_ATTR_UPDATE, ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING, &givenName, 1},
};
     ^^^ error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [15]' to 'LPWSTR'
```

Maybe your compiler version is different, and allows this implicit conversion, but that would seem to be what's upsetting the later call.

Try this, instead:

```
wchar_t gnString[32] = L"givenName";
ADS_ATTR_INFO  attrInfo[] = {
    {gnString, ADS_ATTR_UPDATE, ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING, &givenName, 1},
};
```

You'll probably have similar issues in your initialisation of the `ADSVALUE` structure(s)!

Change:

```
givenName.dwType           = ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
givenName.CaseIgnoreString = L"Janet";
```

To:

```
wchar_t forename[16]       = L"Janet";
givenName.dwType           = ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
givenName.CaseIgnoreString = foreName;
```

Comment: This is not the issue, it compiles on VS 2019

Comment: I guess it can compile! I have set standard to c++17 and using "conformance" mode. But you're right, even the examples given use string literals.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm learning from these sample codes https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/